# How to specify custom y-axis tick interval with pChart

Tags: pchart

I'm wanting my y-axis to show the ticker at intervals of 8. I've set my scale mode to manual with a min of 0 and a max of 48 but it still defaults to showing a tick at intervals of 5.

I haven't seen a setting or option to customise this yet, is there a way to do it?

```
/* Draw the scale */
$scaleSettings = array("Mode"=>SCALE_MODE_MANUAL,"ManualScale"=>array(0=>array("Min"=>1,"Max"=>56)));
$myPicture->drawScale($scaleSettings);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm fairly new to pChart and was looking for a way to do the same thing.  I ended up finding a discussion in pchart's forums about the "Factors" setting for drawScale().  It can be used to set the tick intervals.

So your code would need to be:

```
$scaleSettings = array("Factors"=>array(8));
$myPicture->drawScale($scaleSettings);
```

It's mentioned in the documentation, but I haven't been able to find a whole lot of information on it.  I can't tell you why the number must be in an array, just that it did not work for me what I tried "Factors"=>8.

Here are the docs for drawScale:
http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.doc.draw.scale.html

And here's the discussion I found useful:
http://wiki.pchart.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=397

Answer (score 0):

Try "LabelSkip" keyword. Like;

```
$Settings=array("AxisR"=>150,"AxisG"=>150,"AxisB"=>150,"LabelSkip"=>5);
$MyPicture->drawScale($Settings);
```

Will show every 5th label on x-axis.